# Spark - How to group data by multiple keys with or relationship

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a RDD like the following:

```
[
    Row(device='1', token='aaa', other_value=1),  
    Row(device='1', token='bbb', other_value=1), 
    Row(device='2', token='bbb', other_value=1), 
    Row(device='4', token='ddd', other_value=1), 
    ...
]
```

In order to do some processing (not for aggregation), I need to group rows with the same device or token together. For example, first 3 rows above should be grouped together for further processing. (row 1 and 2 have the same device 1, row 2 and 3 have the same token bbb).

Essentially, I would like to do something like

```
rdd.groupBy(same device or same token)
```

Is it possible in spark?

---

**Update**:

The expected output would be a RDD like this for the above example:

```
[
    [
        Row(device='1', token='aaa', other_value=1),  
        Row(device='1', token='bbb', other_value=1), 
        Row(device='2', token='bbb', other_value=1)
    ],
    [
        Row(device='4', token='ddd', other_value=1)
    ]
]
```

Comment: can you add expected output ?

Comment: if there was a row `Row(device='4', token='bbb', other_value=1)` to which group would this row belong?

Comment: @werner in that case, everything should belong to 1 group. Essentially, it's like a union-find/disjoint set problem. I would love to group anything that has the same device or token together into 1 group

Answer (score 1):

The property to which group a row belongs is transitive. Therefore a simple `groupBy` won't work. One option would be to interpret the data as [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)) and use [GraphFrames](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/graph-analysis/graphframes/user-guide-python.html) to find the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) in the graph. Each row of the input data would be an edge of the graph with source = `device` and destination = `token`.

```python
#setup GraphFrames
import os
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = (
    "--packages graphframes:graphframes:0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12 pyspark-shell"
)

spark = ...

#the input data
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([   Row(device='1', token='aaa', other_value=1),  
    Row(device='1', token='bbb', other_value=1), 
    Row(device='2', token='bbb', other_value=1),     
    Row(device='4', token='ddd', other_value=1)])

df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd)

edges = df \
    .withColumnRenamed("device", "src") \
    .withColumnRenamed("token", "dst")

vertices = edges.select("src").distinct() \
    .union(edges.select("dst").distinct()) \
    .withColumnRenamed("src", "id")

#create a graph and find all connected components
g = GraphFrame(vertices, edges)
cc = g.connectedComponents()

df.join(cc.distinct(), df.device == cc.id) \
    .orderBy("component", "device", "token") \
    .show()
```

Output:

```
+------+-----+-----------+---+------------+
|device|token|other_value| id|   component|
+------+-----+-----------+---+------------+
|     4|  ddd|          1|  4| 60129542144|
|     1|  aaa|          1|  1|335007449088|
|     1|  bbb|          1|  1|335007449088|
|     2|  bbb|          1|  2|335007449088|
+------+-----+-----------+---+------------+
```

All rows with the same value for `component` belong to the same group.